# retrieving "createdAt" and "updatedAt" from Parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, server

I've retrieved rows as objects from a class in `Parse` and store them in an array to use it later in a table view. I could successfully do that for all columns in the class except for two columns which are **createdAt** and **updatedAt** those two are created automatically by `Parse` every time we add a new row.
[image]

When I print the array, I see all the columns except **createdAt** and **updatedAt**.

[image]

This is the function I created to retrieve the data and store it in the array of objects and it works fine except for **createdAt** and **updatedAt**.

[image]

Thanks for help in advanced!

Comment: I think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425537/unable-to-retrieve-updatedat-or-createdat-values-from-parse-objects/25809286

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to retrieve updatedAt or createdAt values from Parse objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425537/unable-to-retrieve-updatedat-or-createdat-values-from-parse-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've found the answer which is that the columns objectId, createdAt and updatedAt that are created automatically by Parse are properties and we have to call them alone and they can't be retrieved with the whole object.

I called the object "article" so I can get the createdAt like this

let theDate = article.createdAt

The type here will be Date? and if you want to embed it within the table view you have to convert to String.